# Howto deal with AnyEvent, RabbitMQ (heartbeat) and long running jobs in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, rabbitmq, fork, anyevent

I am implementing a system for distributed cronjob execution (so called *cron computing cluster*). Cronjobs should be queued into a message queue (RabbitMQ) when the time of action is there. On the other side (the nodes/workers of the cluster) is a Perl daemon utilizing `AnyEvent::RabbitMQ` to receive exactly one cronjob/task/message from the message queue, process the task and request another exactly one cronjob/task/message from the message queue and so on.

I use RabbitMQ's heartbeat feature which is implemented with `AnyEvent::RabbitMQ` to help RabbitMQ identifying broken connections.

Never mind the actual value of the heartbeat interval! I also have very long running jobs that takes days. So setting the interval to somewhat the longest cronjob would take is not an option.

See the following snippet for executing the actual cronjob within the Perl daemon worker. It is implemented within an ´AnyEvent->timer´ to not DoSing RabbitMQ for a message. This method was used due to RabbitMQ's `consume` was prohibited (by management).

```perl
sub _timer_tick {

  $rabbitmq_channel->get(
    queue      => 'job_queue',
    on_success => sub {
      my ($amqp_method) = @_;
      if ( not $amqp_method->{empty} ) {
        pause_timer();
        progress_job($amqp_method);
        resume_timer();
      }
    },
    on_failure => sub { $quit_programm->send( 'RABBITMQ_ERROR', @_ ) },
  );

  return;
}
```

`progress_job()` is where the message gets parsed and the job will be executed. `pause_timer()` and `resume_timer()` controls the `AnyEvent->timer` that triggers `_timer_tick()`.

```perl
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';
sub progress_job {
  my ($amqp_method) = @_;
  my $job = decode_json( $amqp_method->{body}->to_raw_payload() );
  my ( $stdout, $stderr, $exit ) = capture {
    system $job->{execute};
  };
  return;
}
```

The first long running jobs went in and the system "crashes" with various error messages. Sometimes it throws 'Unknown channel id: 1', other times it throws 'Channel has already been closed'. So I did 'dumb debug' (trying to mess with the config) and found out that when the `heartbeat` interval is shorter than the time taken within `progress_job()` those errors will be thrown. After some thinking it makes sense. `progress_job()` is a blocking subroutine and AnyEvent cannot proceed sending heartbeat packages to RabbitMQ.

My first quick thought on solving the blocking-heatbeat issue was to fork and do `progress_job()` in the child process. [AnyEvents documentation on FORK](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent#FORK) points out that it is save to use `fork` when there is no access to the event system (e.g. through AnyEvent) within the child.
Next thought: OK, there is no access to the event system so I can do fork.
BUT: The timer should resume (`resume_timer()`) AFTER `progress_job()` has returned. Theoretically `resume_timer()` would be called right after `fork()` and not after `progress_job()` returns. So I stopped my implementation.

My question: How to solve the last bit? How to `resume_timer()` after `progress_job()` (or in other words the forked child) returns?
I cannot put `resume_timer()` within the child due to forking and the eventing system are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AE can't process events unless the program is blocked using an AE-aware call. `system` is not AE-aware. Use `run_cmd` from [AnyEvent::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent::Util) instead.

Comment: `$run_cmd_cv->recv` gives me `256` instead of expected `1`. The command `perl -E 'exit 1' ; echo $?` also echos `1`. How to receive the actual error code of the executed command?

Comment: bash's `$?` is different than Perl's `$?`. See [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added `$exit = $exit >> 8 if $exit && $exit > 255;` and it works now.

Comment: That doen't make much sense. What about when `$exit & 0x7F` is true? `exit( ($exit & 0x7F) | 0x80 ) if $exit & 0x7F; exit( $exit >> 8 ) if $exit >> 8;` would make more sense. It's also what the shell does.